# SQL Column Not Found: Added earlier in program

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, alter-table

I'm using SQL Server 2008. I have a stored procedure with code that looks like this:

```
if not exists (select column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
where table_name = 'sample_table' and column_name = 'sample_column')    
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE Sample_Table
        ADD Sample_Column NVARCHAR(50)
    END

Update dbo.Sample_Table
SET Sample_Column = '1'
```

When I execute, I get a "Column Not Found" error because the column doesn't originally exist in Sample_Table-it's added in the procedure. What's the correct way to get around this?

My workaround (below) is to wrap the update statement in an EXEC statement, so that it is forced to create the code and execute after the ALTER TABLE step. But is there a better method?

```
EXEC ('
Update dbo.Sample_Table
SET Sample_Column = ''1'' ')
```

Comment: Looking at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx you can see that all similar `ALTER TABLE` statements require a batch separator... the precompiler isn't intelligent enough to scan your scripts for schema changes like that before running the commands.  But what you are doing isn't generally a good idea anyway, so you may want to reconsider your methodology.

Comment: Workaround is ok, but better do not mix DDL and DML statements.

Comment: Is there any reason you would do this in a stored procedure?  It appears to be 1-off code, which is not the best fit for a sproc.  In general, we do deployments via some sort of script versus a store procedure.  Since precompile behavior is different in a sproc, you may be causing a problem that doesn't need to exist.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not really like your workaround, the only other option seems to be separating your DDL logic from the DML one, i.e. one SP will check/create the column (maybe other columns too, as necessary), another SP sets the value(s).

On the other hand, it looks like you are using your UPDATE statement merely as a means of providing a default value for the newly created column. If that is the case, you might consider an entirely different solution: creating a DEFAULT constraint (no need for the `UPDATE` statement). Here:

```
if not exists (select column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
where table_name = 'sample_table' and column_name = 'sample_column')    
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE Sample_Table
        ADD Sample_Column NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT DF_SampleTable_SampleColumn DEFAULT ('1');

        ALTER TABLE Sample_Table
        ALTER COLUMN Sample_Column NVARCHAR(50) NULL;
    END
```

The second `ALTER TABLE` command is there only to drop the `NOT NULL` restriction, as it seems like you didn't mean your column to have it. But if you are fine with `NOT NULL`, then just scrap the second `ALTER TABLE`.